# ssrs 2008 want repeating column headers on Word document export

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word, ssrs-2008

In an SSRS 2008 report that I modified, I changed the report to do the following:
a. Display repeating column headers on each page while the report is executing,
b. Displays repeating report headers on each page when the report is exported as a PDF document.

The problem is when the report is exported to a word document, there are no repeating column
headers past the first page. I would like the column headers to appear on each page of the word document.

Thus can you tell me what I need to do so that repeating column headers appear on each page when the
report is exported to a Word document?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1**
Word does not repeat header rows on pages two and later although you set the **RepeatOnNewPage** property of the static header row in a tablix (table, matrix, or list) to **true**. You can define explicit page breaks into your report to force header rows to appear on new pages. However, because Word applies its own pagination to the rendered report exported to Word, results might vary and the header row might not repeat predictably. The static header row is the row that contains the column headings.

Kindly refer the link [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627455(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627455%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

**Solution2**

Assume one Word page can contains 20 rows. So, you can insert a Parent Group for your subreport, and its group expression is =(RowNumber(Nothing) -1) \ 20 and click the "Add the group header" and enable this group page break function in this group properties window. Delete the table header row and fill in the content into the group header. Now, one group will be in one page, and one group has its own header. But this way is not smart due to it is limited by the number of rows of the word or PDF.

Kindly refer the link
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fd58a159-7462-46d8-af44-2d6eb33066fe/ssrs-2008-when-exporting-to-word-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-functionality-does-not-work?forum=sqlreportingservices

Thanks
Venkat